# Can you apply a progress bar from waitress to a modal Dialog?

Tags: r, shiny, progress-bar

In a `shiny` app, I have a plot which sometimes takes a bit of time to calculate. I would like to show the progress of this calculation with a progressbar from the `waiter` package. Is there a way to apply a `waitress` to a `modalDialog`? Below is a MWE where the `waitress` is applied to the full page, but I would find it way better if I just had one bar on the `modalDialog`.

I have checked the possibilities from the [Demo](https://shiny.john-coene.com/waiter/): Applying it to the `actionButton` does not work in my actual app. Showing it as a notification would work, but I am not aware of any way to display the notification in the center of the screen rather than in a corner. I guess the "on elements" is what I am looking for, but my `modalDialog` does not have an input or output id.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinipsum)
library(waiter)
library(plotly)

complicated_function <- function(){
  waitress <- Waitress$new(theme = "overlay",min = 0,max = 20)
  for(i in 1:20){
    waitress$inc(1)
    Sys.sleep(0.2)
  }
  waitress$close()
  return(random_ggplotly())
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  useWaitress(),
  actionButton("plotButton", "Generate Plot")
)

server <- function(input,output,session){
  modal1 <- modalDialog(
    renderPlotly({
      complicated_function()
    })
  )
  observeEvent(input$plotButton,{
    showModal(modal1)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the attendantBar from the same package:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinipsum)
library(waiter)
library(plotly)

complicated_function <- function(){
  att <- Attendant$new("progress-bar", hide_on_max = TRUE)
  for(i in 1:20){
    att$set(i * 10)
    Sys.sleep(0.2)
   }
  return(random_ggplotly())
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  useAttendant(),
  
  actionButton("plotButton", "Generate Plot")
)

server <- function(input,output,session){
  
  
  modal1 <- modalDialog(
    attendantBar("progress-bar"),
    renderPlotly({

      complicated_function()
    })
    
  )
  observeEvent(input$plotButton,{
    showModal(modal1)
    
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```